# PSD to PNG - good software or website to download all the components?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, png

I don't have Photoshop. I have PSD file with a lot of components. The only site I found for convert it to components is [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) but it doesn't allow me to download all the components at once and the other sites/software only give me the full PNG. Is there a better website or software for this?

Comment: Photoshop CC has **Generator** built in.

Comment: i have no PS, i only have the file

Comment: I'm not sure about website but you could definitely download Gimp the open source photoshop and save each layer needed as a png

Comment: If its creator has already prepared the assets by naming layers like: logo.png, image.jpg and so on, there might be little hope in [slicy](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) if you have mac.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have Photoshop then I'd suggest maybe downloading the free trial of [Creative Cloud](http://www.adobe.com/ca/downloads.html) and installing the app. If you only have this one off need that would probably get you through.

Comment: If the OP puts himself in this situation twice without a solution, then that is his own fault. How about: Don't receive filetypes you can't open and don't agree to jobs you can't finish. -- As a temp solution, this is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

It is the only tool I know wich is able to convert Photoshop CC Files.

You can use it to get an image per layer:

```
convert test.psd out.png
```

(You will get out-0.png, out-1.png...)

or to get one specific layer

```
convert test.psd[2] out.png
```

or to get only one image with all currently visible layers

```
convert test.psd  -flatten out.png
```